# Embedding n (more than one) .txt files in Flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have to embed .txt files in my Flex application. My application has some examples(whose count can be increased later). For each example, I have to embed a different txt file. I know how to use the Embed tag but it requires the use of n Class variables for n txt files I will embed. Is there any way around to achieve this in a more optimal manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's none, as each embed is treated as something separate. You can, however, merge all your text files into a single XML/JSON file as strings, and embed only that file with its class, create one instance and parse it for text file pieces.

Comment: Thanks, Vesper. I think I missed one point, that at one particular time, only one example will be shown in my application. Now, is it possible?

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't matter that only one text file out of many will be shown. Your app will still need the entire set of them being compiled into the SWF, unless you will rely or loaders. And if your set is expandable, you might indeed do better with externally loading files instead of embedding, be it that single big XML/JSON I speak of, or one XML with URLs to get your example files, and the entire set of example files accessible via URLs.